# Correlating Likert data to nominal data

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, categorical-data

I have three different versions of a web page design which I have evaluated using a set of Likert usability scales. How do I (can I??) use SPSS to correlate the usability scales to the different versions to see which web page (if any) is perceived to be most useful? (I'm a stats novice so please explain gently :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not overly familiar with SPSS, the transformation of Likert to nominal data depends on the scale that you have used in the first instance.

For instance, suppose that you have a usability scale from **1** (least useful) to **10** (most useful).

You decide that a ranking of 7 or above is deemed useful, with your nominal variable being **1 = useful**, **0 = not useful**.

Therefore, any value of 7 or above is being replaced with a 1, while that below 7 is being replaced with 0.

While I don't have much information on the structure of your data, I would be inclined to convert the data manually in order to ensure that your nominal variable remains consistent across the three different versions.